# Access nested array parameter in Hugo template

Tags: hugo

I have a nested array defined in the parameter section of a Hugo content item:

```
+++
...
files = [ ["data/2013-08-16/thumbs/thumb_2013-08-16_09:49:32_IMG_7101.JPG","rotate-90"],["data/2013-08-16/thumbs/thumb_2013-08-16_10:39:55_IMG_7113.JPG","rotate-0"] ]
+++
...
```

How can I access the members of the innermost array from a template? I try to do something like:

```
{{ range .Params.files }}
   <div class="grid-item"><img width="100" src="{{ first 1 . }}" class="{{after 1 .}}></div>    
{{ end }}
```

However `{{ first 1 . }}` and `{{ after 1 . }}` return arrays and therefore will be decorated with `[]`. Is there a funtion to rerive a member of an array? Something like `{{ get 0 . }}` or `{{ get 1 . }}`. `.Get` seems to be not for general slices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array access can be done via `{{ index . 0 }}` which is similar to `x[0]` when `.` point so `x`.